# Анимирование невидимости

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

привет кто шарит в анимации xaml можно ли как через xaml сделать картинку невидимой
Питаюсь так не не выходит

```
<DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" 
                         Storyboard.TargetName="logo"
                         From="{Binding ElementName=logo, Path=Visibility}" 
                         To="1" Duration="0:0:0:1"/>
```

Какой тип анимации использовать 
Как вариант есть

```
<DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="logo"
                              From="1.0" To="0" Duration="0:0:0:1"/>
```

картинка все равно существует и воспринимает нажатие кнопок
Update 
Решение

```
<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="logo"
                                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0:1" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}"/>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

Comment: менять прозрачность не пойдет?

Comment: ...оформите решение как ответ